# Mysql key: is single key guaranteed to be faster than compound key?

Tags: mysql, composite-key, compound-key

In the following two scenarios:

```
create table `Table` (
    `id` int(10),
    `column1` int(10),
    `column2` int(10),
    KEY (`column2`)
);
```

and

```
create table `Table` (
    `id` int(10),
    `column1` int(10),
    `column2` int(10),
    KEY (`column1`, `column2`)
);
```

Now  consider the query `select * from Table where column2=xxx;`

Is there any possibility that the second scenario will be faster than the first scenario, for example in the case where the rows just happen to cluster densely on column1?

Or can we say with 100% certainty that the first scenario is always at least as fast as the second scenario?

I tried searching composite/compound key speed but cannot find answer with 100% certainty when compared to single key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any possibility that the second scenario will be faster than the first scenario

Yes.

This is a scenario when the table statistic is so incorrect that server errorneously uses the index instead of table scan. For example, the statistic shows that approximately 1% of rows contains the value `xxx` whereas really this is 50%.

Of course the probability of such situation is extremely low, but it is not zero nevertheless.

`ANALYZE TABLE` will fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Your first index will be faster since the query will be an index scan. Your composite index will actually cause the query to be a slow row scan. The index will only be used when the column you are looking for is leftmost in the index. Since column2 is not leftmost, your index won't be used.

The composite index would only be used for queries like:

- select * from Table where column1='X'
- select * from Table where column1='X' and column2='Y'

The big thing with indexes is knowing how you'll be querying the data. If you don't know, prematurely optimizing may not do you any good.

Comment: OP asks about an exclusion, not about a rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Literal answer:** 100% is not guaranteed; also "single-column" versus "composite" is not the right question, as Erik points out.

**Practical answer:** Given `where column2=xxx`, you should have an index *starting* with `column2`.

**Long answer:**

The database engine applies a lot intelligence toward "caching" indexes and data.  The goal is to make the *typical* query fast *on average*.

If there is not much "churn", blocks of data and indexes are brought into RAM (the "buffer_pool") and they live there.  The *first* query after a restart will have to do some I/O to fetch blocks from disk; this is slow.  Subsequent queries can skip some or all of the fetches; hence they are faster.  That is, *other* queries can *happen to* make _this query faster.  Hence the 100% is defeated.  (And there is no way to achieve "100%" without slowing everything down to a constant, but inefficient, speed.)

More on creating optimal indexes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Let me confuse things further.  In your specific 3-column table, and with your specific `SELECT *`, here is the *usual* pecking order; slowest to fastest

```
INDEX(column2, column1) -- index's BTree is bulkier than the next
INDEX(column2)          -- good (and recommended)
INDEX(column2, column1, id) -- "covering" all of "*" is in the index
```

When building indexes, it is best to collect all the important queries (Select, Update, Delete) together to decide which set of indexes to have.  This Question has only addressed one specific select for that specific schema.